how to start autofill from the last select row in csv file python selenium webdriver after the autofill has stoped
I have created an autofill with python selenium and I have a small problem with it, the autofill stops by itself after it has reached the autofill ROW 15 or 18 or 20 and when I restart the autofill it starts from the beginning then I have the problem that I have the web form 2x-3x with the same data.
Do you perhaps have a solution so that my autofill, for example, the autofill stops at ROW 15 and I restart it, it starts again from ROW 15 so that I do not have the same data several times.

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Imports
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup

name = 0
age = 1
score = 2

with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Web Automation

    for line in csv_reader:

        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get('https://mysite.domain/?page_id=311')
      
        Add_to = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='site-content']")
        Add_to.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        
        driver.get('https://mysite.domain/?page_id=385')
        
        name_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='first_name']")
        name_field.send_keys(line[0])

        age_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='last_name']")
        age_field.send_keys(line[1])

        Adress = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='address_1']")
        Adress.send_keys(line[2])

        Zip = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='postcode']")
        Zip.send_keys(line[3])

        City = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='city']")
        City.send_keys(line[4])

        Phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='phone']")
        Phone.send_keys(line[5])

        Email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='email']")
        Email.send_keys(line[6])

        Submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Submit']")
        Submit.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

One of my attempts didn't really work :(
Web Automation
for line in csv_reader:
csv.reader("let lastrow = $('table').find('tr')[document.querySelectorAll('table tr').length-1];$(lastrow).find('.fa-edit').click();")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://mysite.domain/?page_id=311')...


I would prefer this to be a comment but I dont have enough rep for that. so... Anyways
You can achieve this by implementing a mechanism to track the last processed row and save this state externally, I chose a file to do that for me.
That way, when the script is restarted, we can read the last processed row and start again from there.
Maybe try these steps.

Add a function that can save the last accessed row index from the file and use it to access from where u want the next time

I would suggest you to convert the CSV to list as it's much easier to work with.

Make sure your loop updates from the last processed row.


